# I can wear hat I earned on other site

Tags: support, status-bydesign, winter-bash-2013

I just earned "old hat" on several sites:

> have a user account created in the first month of the site's existence

But not here on Meta yet I am able to wear it on Meta.

Bug, or by design?

Comment: given that there's an "only on this site" checkbox, I'd say by design.

Comment: By design; there is a 'only on this site' checkbox.

Comment: OK, fair enough... 2:20 AM here guess I better go to bed just wanted to be here when hats start rolling out!

Comment: Skipped right over the blog post and FAQ page

Comment: Put my old hat on as soon as I read this and realized I could do it (at least until I figure out how to get the Boba Fett hat)

Comment: @random well, I helped balpha gain the rep cap hat faster... isn't that a noble cause? :)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

By design. This year, you can wear a hat on all sites, even if you earned it on just one (this goes together with the whole "by default, changing your hat changes it on *all* sites" thing).

See [the blog](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2013/12/winter-bash-2013-is-here/):

> **Hats are transferrable across sites!** You read that correctly: this year, if you earn a hat on any site, you can wear it on any participating Stack Exchange site. This was one of our most asked-for feature requests after last year’s event, and it’s a great way for everyone to highlight their achievements on their favorite site across the network.